# Visual understanding of radius of convergence for complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I am examining Needham's proof (Visual Complex Analysis 2.III.2) that $\sum c_k z^k$ converges at $a$ implies absolute convergence (and hence convergence) for $|z| < |a|.$

Despite the book's principal aim of "*understanding through visualisation*", I wonder whether this proof is heavier than necessary.

Can anyone improve upon it?

My best attempt is:

Convergence at $a$ gives us (1) $|c_k a^k| \rightarrow 0$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$, therefore we can find a biggest term, and place an upper bound $M$ on the magnitude of a single term: $|c_k a^k| < M$, so $|c_k| < \frac{M}{|a|^k}$

Suppose now $|z|<|a|.$ Then  $\sum |c_k z^k| = \sum |c_k| |z|^k < M \sum\rho^k$ (where $\rho = \frac{|z|}{|a|}$) $= \frac{M}{1-\rho}$

So (2) the series in question converges absolutely for $|z|<|a|$ as desired.

(1) and (2) can visually be seen to be trivially true, which takes some of the weight off the algebra. However, can the whole thing be seen visually? Is there some improvement?

Comment: Visualizing things is great. Insisting that proofs _must_ be visual strikes me as silly (erm, note that crack is aimed more at a certain author than at you - a book on complex analysis that omits the proof of the Riemann mapping theorem because we can't do it "visually" is just not right. Imo.)

Comment: It's more logically sound to avoid talking about $f(z)$ until you know the series converges at $z.$ I would just deal with the series. Also, you've defined $|f|(z)$ in a strange way; if $f$ is a function, then the notation $|f|$ has a well established meaning.

Comment: @zhw. Ah, I was not aware. Is there a "correct" notation?

Comment: I would avoid "functions" altogether here; it's a result about series. I edited your post a little  to illustrate.